# 避けられたらなって思う　unsure about the なって

Tags: particle-って

I’ve been playing Final Fantasy 8 on the switch in Japanese and I’ve  come across a sentence that has stumped me.

After Squall tells Rinoa that he may have to kill Seifer in a possible prospective battle, Rinoa replies

でも、もちろん...
避けられたらなって思うよ

I’ve been able to read most everything in the game quite comfortably but this sentence has me confused.

“If it can be avoided...”

is what 避けられたら　translates too, which makes sense given the context.

I’m only unsure about the なって part. Is this なる as in the verb “become” conjugated?

Thanks!